# Stub Jquery Event object for Jasmine Testing

Tags: jquery, events, jasmine, stubbing

I want to create a jasmine test for a function that is an event handler.

The function looks like

```
someFunction: function(event) {
    var x = this.$(event.currentTarget).data('event');
    //do something
}
```

I would like to stub the jquery event using the $.Event jquery object. I am not sure how to add the currentTarget property to the event such that the call

```
$(event.currentTarget).data('event');
```

returns something that will make the function proceed to completion.

eg. I expect

```
 $(event.currentTarget).data('event');
```

to return say 'columnOne'